# How to align tables along side text in html CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, format, alignment

[image: This is what I want my output to be]

```
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <tr>
            <td width="35" height="20"></td>
            <td width="35" height="20"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I know that I've to create three tables using above code side by side but the question is how can I use hyphen between them and write DOB text on the left side of the first tables. 
This is my assignment and I've to do this using tables only.

Answer (score 3):

Flex boxs would be the best solution.

First you need to wrap all of the elements in a `div`

The we can turn that div into a flex container with `display:flex`

We use `align-items` and justify-content`` for the alignment of the flex items.

Hope this helps:)

```css
#dob {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 360px;
}

#dob h4{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id='dob'>
  <h4>Date of Birth:</h4>
  <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
      <td width="35" height="20"></td>
      <td width="35" height="20"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <span>-</span>
  <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
      <td width="35" height="20"></td>
      <td width="35" height="20"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <span>-</span>
  <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
      <td width="35" height="20"></td>
      <td width="35" height="20"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: @Dayley you added in your edit *Note: he said using tables only. This uses CSS aswell as HTML tables. Is this allowed?*. This should have been a comment so I can reply in this thread

Comment: @Dayley He stated he used 3 tables for the fields. He actually added those table. Also he taged to the question ``css`` allowing the use of css on the solution.